# grep output of a command sometimes works.. Sometimes not?

Tags: grep, gnu

please consider the following:

```
$ cd ~/.emacs.d/lisp/tabbar
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.

$ git pull | grep -q "Already" ; echo $?
0
```

Still with me? Now:

```
$ cd ~/src/emacs-tmp/trunk
$ bzr up                           
Tree is up to date at revision 108837 of branch /home/px/src/emacs-tmp/trunk

$ bzr up | grep -q "Tree" ; echo $?     
Tree is up to date at revision 108837 of branch /home/px/src/emacs-tmp/trunk
1
```

Questions :

- Why is the return code of grep "0" (found) in the 1st case and
  "1" (not found) in the 2nd ?
- Why is the output of the first (git pull) command
  hidden when grepping for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like bzr is outputting to the standard error device (`/dev/stderr`), while `grep` is only inspecting the standard input. You can confirm or deny this guess by trying to redirect `stderr` to `stdin`:

```
bzr up 2>&1 | grep -q "Tree" ; echo $?
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your "visible" command is output'ting to stderr, not stdout. grep only looks in stdout, unless you redirect with 2>&1.

Therefore, try

```
bzr up 2>&1 | grep -q "Tree" ; echo $?
```

Answer (score 1):

- Why is the return code of grep "0" (found) in the 1st case and "1" (not found) in the 2nd ?

Probably because in the first case the output is on stdout, and in the second case its on stderr. You can add a "2>&1" to the commands to throw everything to stadout.

- Why is the output of the first (git pull) command hidden when grepping for it ?

Because you said "-q", which tells grep to shut up :-)